# Lint errors using dji mobile sdk

Tags: android, gradle, androidx, dji-sdk

After following the steps here: https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html#android-studio-project-integration to add the SDK to a newly created androidX project in android studio, lint fails to build with the following errors:

```
  ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.57/5c96e34bc9bd4cd6870e6d193a99438f1e274ca7/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.57.jar: Error: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: javax.naming.directory. Referenced from org.bouncycastle.cert.dane.fetcher.JndiDANEFetcherFactory. [InvalidPackage]
  ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.57/5c96e34bc9bd4cd6870e6d193a99438f1e274ca7/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.57.jar: Error: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: javax.naming. Referenced from org.bouncycastle.cert.dane.fetcher.JndiDANEFetcherFactory.1. [InvalidPackage]
  ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.lmax/disruptor/3.3.9/7898f8e8dc2d908d4ae5240fbb17eb1a9c213b9b/disruptor-3.3.9.jar: Error: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: java.lang.management. Referenced from com.lmax.disruptor.dsl.BasicExecutor. [InvalidPackage]
```

This can be avoided with a `lint.xml` file. Is this a problem? Does this have the potential to crash an app when it tries to use the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

DJI Mobile SDK is not compatible with AndroidX projects. I had the same issue a few days ago while trying to create an app using Material Design and DJI MSDK.